# swift: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: subscript is get-only

Tags: arrays, swift, 2d

```
import Cocoa

struct MyData {
    let t: TimeInterval
    let q: Int
}

extension Collection where Index == Int, Element == [MyData] {
    mutating func add(_ new: MyData) {
        guard !self.isEmpty else {
            self = [[new]] as! Self
            return
        }
    
        self[self.count - 1].append(new) /// <---- how to fix it???
    }
}

var myData: [[MyData]] = []
myData.add(MyData(t: Date().timeIntervalSince1970, q: 1))

print(myData)
```

It's a mutating func and I can't access last value to add new element. Why is that?
Also, `self.last` is not working anymore (I use xcode 13 beta 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend `MutableCollection`. A normal `Collection` does not support setting through subscripts, the mutable counterpart does.

```
extension MutableCollection where Index == Int, Element == [MyData] {
  //...
}
```